# How to filter query using column entry in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Query I need to run at multiple sites, the query will be the same except for the "Site-ID"  The site id is stored in another table on each database, so I figure it would be easier to automate this and write the query to grab the correct siteid right in the where clause instead of changing the query 20 times.

My query is:

```
Select *
from customers
where bactive = 'true' and siteid = 'Site1'
```

The Site is stored in the table "Account"  So I figured I could do something like this:

```
select *
from customers
where bactive = 'true' and siteid = database.dbo.accounts.siteid
```

This didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But which database.dbo.accounts.siteid should be used? All of them, or just one?

Comment: You need to add "customer.*" in Select Clasue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site id is identical to your server name, you could try something like :

```
select *
from customers
where bactive = 'true' and siteid =  @@ServerName
```

where @@serverName is the system name of the SQL Server Instance

If your site id differs from the Server Instance name, you could add the instance name as a property in your Accounts table, so you could do the link between your instance name and your site id:

```
select *
from customers
where bactive = 'true' and siteid =  (SELECT Tbl_Account.siteid From Tbl_Account Where Tbl_Account.serverName = @@ServerName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
  If Database is on same server

```
select Customer.* from customers c 
INNER JOIN database.dbo.accounts s ON c.siteid = c.siteid    
where c.bactive = 'true'
```

If Database is on other  server

```
select Customer.* from customers c 
INNER JOIN ServerName.database.dbo.accounts s ON c.siteid = c.siteid    
where c.bactive = 'true'
```

Comment: @jarlh..yup.need to add it in inner join.. will edit it now